# A SQL query that used to work does not work anymore

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that works on older version of MySQL4 but won't work on my current version of 5.5
I'm hoping someone can see what I can't see with this.

```
select tblprefix_groups_permissions.permission_name
  from tblprefix_groups_permissions, tblprefix_users, tblprefix_permissions
 where tblprefix_groups_permissions.permission_name = tblprefix_permissions.permission_name
 and tblprefix_groups_permissions.group_id = tblprefix_users.group_id
 and (tblprefix_users.user_id = '==NUMERIC ID=='
 and (tblprefix_permissions.permission_name = 'ADMIN::SETTINGS::VIEW'
 or tblprefix_permissions.permission_name = 'ALL'))
```

The SQL statement should be pretty self explanitory as to what it does, I don't see where the hangup could be. It is suppost to return a list if it returns nothing then the user is rejected.

Comment: What is `ADMIN::SETTINGS::VIEW''`? Certainly not MySQL code. The quotes appear to be in the wrong place. `'ADMIN::SETTINGS::VIEW'` if it is indeed a string...

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: The user I have logged in has the permission: ADMIN::SETTINGS::VIEW granted to them in the tblprefix_group_permissions table but it does not let them into the restricted area. If I login an admin with the permission of ALL they can get in no problem. It's basicly not putting 2 and 2 togeather ie: Permission thats presented to the query and the permission from the tblprefix_groups_permissions table

Comment: while you are fixing it, get rid of that awful, implicit join syntax. Really this is the 21st century now, not 1991.

Comment: Joins are perfectly legal and they will be used because they do have a perpose.

Comment: @Manvaril, HLGEM was asking you to use the explicit [`join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) syntax... which has been the standard for a few decades now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is correct, I overlooked the fact that the statement also checks to make sure the Permission is in the Master Permissions table ie: tblprefix_permissions.permission_name I had not put the permission into the Master Permissions table yet

So that makes me stupid or just tired LOL sorry guys, good work though and thanks for the quick responses

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have wrongly placed the quotes here:

```
ADMIN::SETTINGS::VIEW''
```

Anyway... are you sure that works in MySQL 4?

BTW, you can remove the outer brackets.

Comment: That was a miss paste of my permission LOL my bad